# Limiting the search query to run faster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Yes yes yes! I know! This is totally wrong to pass SQL in rails like the command below but I promise!:) it is just for some benchmark purposes

```
  @medications = TestPharmOrderMain.select("brand_name,form,dose,generic_name as alternative,sum (order_count)
  as total_count
  ,sum(order_cost) as total_cost").group("brand_name,form,dose,generic_name").limit(5)
```

The PostgresQL that I am running this REST service on it has two million rows and it takes like four minutes to return me the JSON from this query which is impossible to develop against it.

Is there a way I can change this query to for example only look at the first twenty rows in the DB and not two million rows so it runs faster for my dev purposes?

Answer (score 2):

If this is for dev purposes do the smart thing and create a tiny database that is representative of the whole system.  You can do this with a create table as select statement:

```
Create table my_test_table  
as    
select brand_name,form,dose,generic_name as alternative,sum (order_count)
  as total_count
  ,sum(order_cost) as total_cost  
from table  
  group by brand_name,form,dose,generic_name
  limit 5
```

Now you can point your test query to `my_test_table` and it will only have 5 records and will therefore be quite fast.

Now you can also offset this to something like [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/), which is essentially a framework that is laid on top of XUnit.  So this can be easily integrated into your testing that is done in what I presume is RubyUnit.

Comment: thanks but still is there a way I can tell my query above to hey just run that select on your first 100 rows ?

Comment: @EricFromSouthPark you could but that is completely avoiding the point of having repeatable tests, which your query is not able to do.

Comment: Can you show me how?  I was thinking of adding a "limit 10" to the end of "select" statement before it goes to group by part, but that didn't work either. Still it first goes through the table then return 10 of those..

Comment: Woot4Moo's suggestion is the way to go. You'll have to rip out your limit code anyways when you go to the million row dataset.

You could also filter it by adding a where clause.